# Using LLVM to traverse AST

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, clang, llvm

Are there any helper methods to traverse the AST, basic blocks etc. generated by LLVM compiler for a C code ?

Comment: If you're asking about llvm-c interface, than take a look at LLVMGetBasicBlocks, LLVMGetFirstInstruction, LLVMGetBasicBlockTerminator, etc. If you're after C++ - see any of the  numerous LLVM passes for an inspiration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to load a module (from a .bc file compiled from a .c file by `clang -emit-llvm`) and traverse its functions, basic blocks, etc., then you might want to start with the [`llvm::Module` class](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Module.html). It has functions for iterating through global variables and functions. Then the [`llvm::Function` class](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Function.html) has functions for iterating through basic blocks. Then the [`llvm::BasicBlock` class](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1BasicBlock.html) has functions for iterating through instructions.

Or if you'd prefer, you can traverse the AST structure created by Clang. Here's some example code: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/06/08/basic-source-to-source-transformation-with-clang/.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it is impossible to do full operations on the AST in LLVM. Because the LLVM pass works on bitcode level not on the AST. I think what you want is an AST iterator.

You could refer to Chapter 3 in [Artem Degrachev: Clang Static Analyzer: A Checker Developer's Guide](https://github.com/haoNoQ/clang-analyzer-guide/releases/download/v0.1/clang-analyzer-guide-v0.1.pdf).

Clang now have a [page](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/checker_dev_manual.html) for checker developers. You could find more following the link.